# MySQL row level locking showing syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, locking

I'm trying to implement Row Level Locking in my application using MySQL/PHP.

As mentioned in this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-lock-modes.html

But when I'm trying to execute these queries.

```
SELECT * FROM account WHERE id = 13 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;

SELECT * FROM account WHERE id > 13 FOR UPDATE;
```

its giving me following error:

```
SELECT * FROM account WHERE id = 13 LOCK IN SHARE MODE
 LIMIT 0, 25 

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2
```

I'm using version mysql 5.6.23.

Comment: It says error on `LIMIT 0, 25`. Have you tried removing that?

Comment: I'm not using LIMIT clause there

Comment: There is a LIMIT clause in your example

Comment: then insert the semicolon where you have left it off or remove the stray `LIMIT 0, 25`. but it seems you are using it per the error.

Comment: Actually its showing that clause in error but while executing query I'm only doing `SELECT * FROM account WHERE id = 13 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;`